# ajax+rails enviar datos ajax a controlador

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#score').on('click',function () {

        alert("hola");
        var score=4;
        console.log("dentro de click");

        $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "<%=games_create_path%>",
                 dataType:'json',
                 data: {puntos: 4},
                 success: function(msg) {
                     console.log("conseguido");
                     alert("conseguido");
                 },
                 error: function(msg) {
                    console.log("Sorry...");
                    console.log(msg);
                    console.log(msg.responseText);
                  }
        })

  });
});
```

Mi idea es que cuando el usuario haga clic sobre un enlace que lleva el identificador `#score`, *ajax* se comunique con un controlador que tengo en `games_create_path`, y el controlador guarde en la base de datos el número 4 en un *field* llamado `puntos`v(es un *field* que está dentro de una tabla en la base de datos.).

Duda: No sé si estoy comunicando bien con el controlador.

El controlador:

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @games = Game.all
  end

  def new
    @game = Game.new
  end

  def create
    @game=Game.new(task_params)
    @game.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end

    @game.save
  end

  private
    def task_params
      params.require(:game).permit(:puntos)
    end
end
```

Rutas:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post 'games/create', 'games#create'
  get 'games/show'

  root 'games#index'
end
```

Error:

> jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:10255
>   POST localhost:3000/%3C%=games_create_path%%3E 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Tu código no funciona correctamente debido a que estás enviando tus parámetros sin agrupación (i.e. `data: { puntos: 4 }`, pero tu controlador espera una agrupación (i.e. `params.require(:game).permit(:puntos)`).

Puedes cambiar el *script* o el controlador; yo me inclino más por la primera opción, lo cual se vería así:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<%= games_create_path %>",
  dataType:'json',
  data: {
    game: { puntos: 4 }
  },
  success: function(msg) {
    console.log("conseguido");
    alert("conseguido");
  },
  error: function(msg) {
    console.log("Sorry...");
    console.log(msg);
    console.log(msg.responseText);
  }
});
```

Además estás guardando dos veces `@game` en tu controlador, pero con una vez que lo hagas es suficiente:

```
def create
  @game=Game.new(task_params)
  @game.save

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

En cuanto al error:

> jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:10255
>   POST localhost:3000/%3C%=games_create_path%%3E 404 (Not Found)

El problema es que el archivo donde tienes el código de javascript es terminación  `.js` y debería ser `.js.erb` para que el código `<%= games_create_path %>` sea sustituido correctamente por la URL adecuada.

Por último, tienes un error en tus rutas, debes utilizar `to:` para indicar a qué acción apunta la ruta:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post 'games/create', to: 'games#create'
  get  'games/show'

  root 'games#index'
end
```

---

**BONUS**

Podrías actualizar tus rutas utilizando `resources` ya que no estás utilizando acciones personalizadas; además, es mejor práctica que `root` siempre vaya hasta arriba de tus rutas:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'games#index'

  resources :games, only: [:show, :create]
end
```

Considera que con el código anterior, tu ruta ahora la podrás obtener a través de *helper* `games_path`, por lo que deberás actualizar tu código:

```
url: "<%= games_path %>",
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta... lo he intentado, pero sin éxito. ¿Puedes ser que el URL no lo esté escribiendo correctamente?

Comment: @ninithblue ¿Qué error te muestra el log? Si estás utilizando las rutas estándar de rails, entonces deberías cambiar  `games_create_path` por `games_path`. Si tienes duda, agrega el código del archivo _config/routes.rb_ a tu pregunta.

Comment: Rails.application.routes.draw do

  post 'games/create', 'games#create'

  get 'games/show'
  root 'games#index'

end

Comment: En el log me muestra el siguiente error: jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:10255 POST http://localhost:3000/%3C%=games_create_path%%3E 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @ninithblue El error se debe a como estás nombrando tu archivo `.js`; he actualizado la respuesta con la solución.